# Why only related processes can only communicate using pipe() (IPC)?

Tags: unix, ipc, pipe

why does there is limitation that with pipe() only parent and child process can communicate, why not unrelated processes?
why can't two children of a process can't communicate using pipe()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There do have limitation.

Pipe use `fd` to read/write data, `fd` is per-process, a process maintain a `fd` table, child inherit the `fd` table when fork, and each inherited `fd` refer to the same `open file` as in parent process, which is maintained by kernel.

---

> Processes that communicate via the same pipe should be related.

It means, the 2 processes should both aware of the 2 `fd` of the pipe.

---

`<TLPI>` says:

> The pipe should be created by a common ancestor before the series of `fork()` calls that led to the existence of the processes.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such limitation. Any two processes which have a means of obtaining references to each end of the pipe can communicate. A process can even communicate with itself using a pipe.

Any process could obtain a reference to one of the ends of a pipe using any of the following generic means of communicating file descriptors between processes. Pipes are not special in this respect.

- The process itself called `pipe()` and obtained file descriptors for both ends.
- The process received the file descriptor as `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary data through a socket.
- The process obtained the file descriptor from another arbitrary process using platform-specific means like `/proc/<pid>/fd` on Linux.
- (There might be other methods.)
- The process inherited the file descriptor from an ancestor (direct or indirect) that obtained it using one of the aforementioned methods.